# How does wf_simulator works with gnss?

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have read the source code "wf_simulator_core" "op_global_planner_core"and other code depends to those two cpp files.

**I wonder know how wf_simulator localizes with gnss ,and show initial pose on the global path in rviz or does it have other forms?**

I know how to use rviz to localize(2D Pose Estimate),but don't know how with GNSS.

I can't find any connection from wf_simulator to any other localized source code by using GNSS,can someone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358068/how-does-wf_simulator-works-with-gnss?/) by [fantasyplus](https://answers.ros.org/users/57042/fantasyplus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-07-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-07-27**:
@mitsudome-r I know you're familiar with `wf_simulator` - can you help here? I'm pretty sure that localizing using only GNSS is a separate issue from `wf_simulator` but I haven't used AI recently enough to be confident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will answer about "how wf_simulator localizes with gnss".

In the `wf_simulator`, the GNSS info is used for the initialization as a code, but in fact, it is used to move the vehicle position by GNSS in the simulation.

By connecting the GNSS to the `wf_simulator`, the vehicle position is constantly updated when the GNSS data is received. This will drive the simulator and some topics that other Autoware modules need is published (e.g. `/current_pose`, `current_velocity`, `vehicle_status`, and TF from map to base_link).

The following is how to connect the GNSS data to the `wf_sinulator`.

1. launch the runtime manager.
2. setup data (load pcd map, vector map, TF (world_to_map and baselink_to_localizer). Please follow the [ROSBAG Demo document](https://github.com/Autoware-AI/autoware.ai/wiki/ROSBAG-Demo).
3. run the Rviz and select the autoware config file following the document.
4. run the rosbag including the gnss data (the `sample_moriyama_150324.bag` of the ROSBAG demo includes `/nmea_sentence` topic)
5. run the `nmea2tfpose` node in the runtime manager. (with the `sample_moriyama_150324.bag`, you need click the [app] button and select the `7` for the Plane number.) Then, the `nmea2tfpose` node starts and publishes the `/gnss_pose` topic.
6. run the `wf_simulator` in the runtime manager with initialize source being `GNSS` (select on [app] window).

Then, you will see the lidar sensor data is visualized on the Rviz (not as well localized as the NDT).

If you want to use the GNSS data with only for the initialization, you need to stop publishing the `/gnss_pose` after initialization is done (just kill the node by clicking the checkbox again).

I hope this would be helpful for you.

---

Originally posted by [TakaHoribe](https://answers.ros.org/users/42648/takahoribe/) with karma: 181 on 2020-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fantasyplus](https://answers.ros.org/users/57042/fantasyplus/) on 2020-08-01**:
Thanks for you detailed answer!!
I reproduce the wf_simulator car moving with only demo gnss data successfully ,and I will try it on my own data and map.
BTW,do you know how to create the correct vector map for autoware?I create a map by Tier4(V1.12) and op_global_planner can't show globalpath on that map(with rviz goals config),do you know why?

**Comment by [TakaHoribe](https://answers.ros.org/users/42648/takahoribe/) on 2020-08-02**:
@fantasyplus Sorry, I'm not familiar with the vectormap. If you couldn't create any short path from any points, maybe some necessary data is not in your vector map and the related topic is not published. Is there any non-published topic which the op_global_planner subscribes?

**Comment by [fantasyplus](https://answers.ros.org/users/57042/fantasyplus/) on 2020-08-05**:
I have done it successfully!Thanks for response.